# Ubuntu 16.04 apps launched with user appear zoomed

Tags: permissions, dell, sudo, display-resolution

I don't know if I am writing on the right page but there is something starting to bother me a lot.

I have a dell XPS 13 9370 that shipped with Ubuntu 16.04. The screen is a 1920x1080 (so not a 4K problem)

Here's the problem. When I launch some apps such as Wireshark, GNS3 or Packet Tracer with the sudo command, everything is good and the scale/resolution are perfect.

But when I don't launch them with sudo, they appear zoomed/with a bad resolution.

I tried to add more permissions (app by app) with the user but nothing works.
Also, I didn't find someone with the same problem as mine.

Thank you :)

Comment: try looking into `Unity Tweak Tool` or into HiDPI

Comment: Yeah, I already looked into the tool, but I don't know what to do with HiDPI